# Using Stylebot I have completely remove the rating system from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

This will make my experience much more enjoyable.

Not sure how even the edits were removed from history, but I removed the entire stack exchange system using css modifications on the user-end with stylebot, so that I would never see the voting system. I did the same using javascript to find any votes referenced in comments and remove not only the one comment but also all comments by a particular user specified based on if undesirable comments are in the comments fields.

I am looking forward to using the new Stack Overflow without having to see stupid people downvoting my valid questions.

I will either see an answer or not see an answer. So I could care less if I am downvoted from now on. Because now I will never know.

I included META in this. So I won't see downvotes on here either.

I have also removed my score as well so I will also never see my score. The only thing I will see from now on is my badges, unless I specifically visit the Reputation tab on my profile, which I will never do.

Comment: @superuser Your question has never been edited, nor has it been redacted and the only deleted comments are you swearing at us. If there is information missing then it is because you did not put it there.

Comment: The only edits to your question were made by you.  The downvoted were due to your vulgar language towards the entire community.  Retraction of a question requires multiple moderators, this didn’t happen, your question would not be worth that effort.  **Again, your question being downvoted, is due to word you call community users.**  I have also flagged this question for being rude, since it calls community users, stupid

Answer (score 14):

This is fairly nonsensical. Downvotes are supposed to let you know you've made a mistake, not to make you feel bad. If you can't see the downvotes, you can't fix the mistake, so you'll get more. Eventually you'll get too many downvotes on too many questions and [won't be able to ask at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294) -- you'll probably notice then, but it'll be extremely difficult to fix at that point

This is equivalent to you inventing a way to not feel pain anymore, and proclaiming that you're now immortal

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be getting a bit worked up about downvotes here.

I don't want to be mean, but some of your recent questions are borderline offtopic and require information that you cannot reasonably expect anyone here to have.

Your question asking whether any current PC can emulate a PS3 is fundamentally unanswerable by anyone except hardware gurus who have highly intimate knowledge of every piece of equipment in that console.  The processor is a custom PowerPC with several subprocessor cores alongside it and emulation costs for that alone would be huge.  The graphics may be standard, but you need to convert and emulate the hardware functions to make the graphics card work.  In short, the question is subjective and *cannot be reasonably answered* by anyone here.

For that you'd be better off finding a community dedicated to PS3 emulation.

Downvotes aren't meant to be hostile but simply an indication that you may want to look at asking your question differently.  Is it really appropriate here?  Are you asking for something that cannot reasonably expect someone to know the answer to, given that you couldn't find an answer in the first place?

Take it easy, enjoy the site.